# Python3 - "NameError: ... " when importing from Experta

Tags: python, import, conda, nameerror, python-3.8

Hello,
I installed Experta in a Conda environment using Python 3.8.3 and all my programs work fine, but when I try to run this code importing Experta libraries I am having the following error: "NameError: name 'Fact' is not defined".

```
from random import choice
from experta import *


class Light(Fact):
    """Info about the traffic light."""
    pass


class RobotCrossStreet(KnowledgeEngine):
    @Rule(Light(color='green'))
    def green_light(self):
        print("Walk")

    @Rule(Light(color='red'))
    def red_light(self):
        print("Don't walk")

    @Rule(AS.light << Light(color=L('yellow') | L('blinking-yellow')))
    def cautious(self, light):
        print("Be cautious because light is", light["color"])


engine = RobotCrossStreet()
engine.reset()
engine.declare(Light(color=choice(['green', 'yellow', 'blinking-yellow', 'red'])))
engine.run()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "experta.py", line 2, in <module>
  from experta import *
File "/home/karuro/Documents/Magierin/UPN/IntelligentSystems/Experta/experta.py", line 5, in <module>
  class Light(Fact): 
NameError: name 'Fact' is not defined
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: You really should never do `from experta import *` starred imports are bad. I am not familiar with this library, I can only surmise you expect it to contain `Fact` but apparently it doesn't. Why do you think it should?

Comment: Wait, did you name the file `experta.py`? Don't do that, that is shadowing the library you installed. Please **always** post the full error message as *formatted text I. The question itself** don't post images/screenshots or links.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It worked by copying the file with another name. Thanks for you help and suggestions, I edit the question to show the error in text format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem executing with the name "experta.py".

Solution:
Clone the file with a different name and rerun the program.

Answer (score 0):

check whether experta is installed or not, if it's not try installing with --user(root)

```
pip install experta --user
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It is well installed, the problem was the file name.

Comment: @Karuro please upvote or tick my answer, so other can find it useful

Comment: I did, but I don't have enough reputation for it to be reflected on the page.